# dict object is not callable

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle

Here is my python program which is making connection with mongodb*

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.test
names = db.names
item =names.find_one()
print item('name')
```

And, I am getting this error

```
C:\Users\hpg6\Desktop>python mycon.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycon.py", line 15, in <module>
    print (item('name'))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 6):

This line

```
print item('name')
```

Should be

```
print(item['name'])
```

If `item` is a `dict`, it thinks you are trying to call a function `()` instead of lookup a value with a key `[]`

Comment: If Python 2, then it's `print item['name']`, right?  OP doesn't indicate that he's using Python 3.

Comment: OP commented on my post noting that they were using python 3 (though they deleted that comment now)

Answer (score 0):

You are using round brackets, try `print (item['name'])`